# Webpack unable to get json file

Tags: json, webpack

I am new to Webpack and I am having a hard time to understand how I can access the content of my json file being added in `entry` and loaded using `json-loader`:

```
entry :
  en: {
    `${config.basePaths.tmp}script.js`,
    `${config.basePaths.tmp}en.json`
  }
},
output: {
  publicPath: '/js/',
  path: `${config.paths.scripts.dist}`,
  filename: `[name].script.js`
},
module: {
  loaders: [
    {
      test: /\.js$/,
      exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
      loader: 'babel-loader',
      query: {
        presets: ['es2015']
      }
    },
    {
      test: /\.coffee$/,
      loader: 'coffee-loader'
    },
    {
      test: /\.json$/,
      loader: 'json-loader'
    }
  ]
}
```

The object is added to my output file (en.script.js) but I have no clue how to access it... It looks like this:

```
function(module, exports) {

    module.exports = {
        "en": {
            "title": "I love webpack",
            "something": "else"
        }
    };
}
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You should not put a JSON file as the entry point. Entry points are meant to be the starting point of your app and if you specify multiple files per entry point it's just to include them in the same bundle, but they don't really interact with each other (see [Concepts - Entry Points](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/entry-points/)).

Instead with webpack you can import files that are not JavaScript, such as `.json`, and if you have an appropriate loader it will turn that into valid JavaScript which you can use just as any other JavaScript you import. So in your `script.js` (your entry point) you can import the JSON with:

```
import enJson from './en.json';
```

Now you can use `enJson` as you want, which contains the JavaScript representation of `en.json`. And by the way remove that from your entry, because webpack will figure out which files are used by looking what is imported from your entry point (and all its dependencies).

```
entry : {
  en: `${config.basePaths.tmp}script.js`,
},
```